# Testing with jest+enzyme, mock functions is called twice for no reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to learn Jest and Enzyme but I'm having a problem I can't find a solution to, this is my test.. it's not very good I know but I'm learning:

```
import * as apiMock from '../api';

const fakePostId = '1';
const fakePersona = 'Fake';

jest.mock('../api', () => {
    return {
        fetchAllComments: jest.fn(() => {
            return [];
        }),
        filterComments: jest.fn(() => {
            return [];
        }),
        createCommentObject: jest.fn(() => {
            return [];
        }),
    };
});

test('checks if functions are called after didMount', () => {
    const component = shallow(
        <Comments postId={fakePostId} currentPersona={fakePersona} />
    );

    const spySetComments = jest.spyOn(
        component.instance(),
        'setCommentsFromLocalStorage'
    );

    component.instance().componentDidMount();

    expect(spySetComments).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    //Don't know why these are called 2! times, I can't see why removing componentDidMount makes it 0.
    expect(apiMock.fetchAllComments).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(apiMock.filterComments).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}
```

The problem is `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` fails with reason:

> Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called
>   two times.

But I don't know why.
`setCommentsFromLocalStorage` only runs once, and that is the function that sohuld run from componentDidMount and execute these api calls once.

```
ReactComponent looks like this:

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CreateNewComment from './CreateNewComment';
import SingleComment from './SingleComment';
import * as api from '../api';

class Comments extends Component {
  state = {
    comments: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setCommentsFromLocalStorage();
  }

  setCommentsFromLocalStorage = (postId = this.props.postId) => {
    const fetchedComments = api.fetchAllComments();
    const comments = api.filterComments(fetchedComments, postId);
    this.setState({ comments });
  };

  removeComment = commentId => {
    api.removeComment(commentId);
    this.setCommentsFromLocalStorage();
  };

  renderCommentList = (comments, currentPersona) =>
    comments.map(comment => (
      <SingleComment
        {...comment}
        currentPersona={currentPersona}
        key={comment.id}
        onClick={this.removeComment}
      />
    ));

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="py-2">
        <h2 className="text-indigo-darker border-b mb-4">Comments</h2>
        {this.renderCommentList(this.state.comments, this.props.currentPersona)}
        <CreateNewComment
          postId={this.props.postId}
          author={this.props.currentPersona}
          updateComments={this.setCommentsFromLocalStorage}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Comments.propTypes = {
  postId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  currentPersona: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Comments;
```

Answer (score 2):

`componentDidMount` gets called during `shallow()`.

---

This means that `setCommentsFromLocalStorage` gets called which calls `fetchAllComments` and `filterComments` *all during that initial `shallow()` call*.

`api` has already been mocked so it records those calls to `fetchAllComments` and `filterComments`.

---

Once that has all happened, the spy is created for `setCommentsFromLocalStorage` and `componentDidMount` *gets called again* (which calls `fetchAllComments` and `filterComments` again).

The spy for `setCommentsFromLocalStorage` then correctly reports that it was called once (since it only existed during the *second* call to `componentDidMount`).

The spies on `fetchAllComments` and `filterComments` then correctly report that they were called *two times* since they existed *during both calls* to `componentDidMount`.

---

The easiest way to fix the test is to clear the mocks on `fetchAllComments` and `filterComments` before the call to `componentDidMount`:

```
apiMock.fetchAllComments.mockClear();  // clear the mock
apiMock.filterComments.mockClear();  // clear the mock

component.instance().componentDidMount();

expect(spySetComments).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // SUCCESS
expect(apiMock.fetchAllComments).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // SUCCESS
expect(apiMock.filterComments).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // SUCCESS
```

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this? starting with removing the line `component.instance().componentDidMount();`    I tried changing the spy to `const spySetComments = jest.spyOn(
        Comments.prototype,
        'setCommentsFromLocalStorage'
    );` but only get Cannot spy the setCommentsFromLocalStorage property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

Comment: @indiehjaerta yes, `setCommentsFromLocalStorage` is an instance property so it won't exist until the instance exists but `componentDidMount` gets called during the creation of the instance.  So spying on instance properties called during `componentDidMount` requires that you set up your spy and call `componentDidMount` again.  You can clear the mocks on your api spies, though.  I updated my answer with that solution.

Comment: @indiehjaerta you're welcome, glad to hear it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Use `beforeEach` and `afterEach` to mock and mockRestore the spies, respectively.

This is explained in the [Setup and Teardown](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown) section in Jest docs.